# Handling Mysql Spatial datatypes in Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, geospatial

How to handle mysql spatial datatypes in eloquent ORM?, This include how to create migration, insert spatial data and performing spatial query's. If there is not actual solutions exists, is there any workarounds?

Comment: Maybe this could help you out: http://www.codetutorial.io/geo-spatial-mysql-laravel-5/

Comment: The link provided by @haakym is so helpful. Laravel does not support these types natively (look here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php) but you always can run a DB:statement() in your migrations or even, extended the Blueprint class and add your own methods to support those datatypes. Personally I use the DB statement approach.

Answer (score 13):

A workaround I have implemented a while ago is to have a latitude and longitude fields on the model with the following validations (see [Validator class](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation)):

```
$rules = array('latitude' => 'required|numeric|between:-90,90',
                            'longitude'=>'required|numeric|between:-180,180',)
```

The magic comes on the [boot method](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events) of the model, which sets the correct value of the spatial point field:

```
/**
 * Boot method
 * @return void
 */
public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function($eloquentModel){

        if(isset($eloquentModel->latitude, $eloquentModel->longitude)){
            $point = $eloquentModel->geoToPoint($eloquentModel->latitude, $eloquentModel->longitude);
            $eloquentModel->setAttribute('location',  DB::raw("GeomFromText('POINT(" . $point . ")')") );
        }

    });

    static::updated(function($eloquentModel){

        if(isset($eloquentModel->latitude, $eloquentModel->longitude)){
            $point = $eloquentModel->geoToPoint($eloquentModel->latitude, $eloquentModel->longitude);
            DB::statement("UPDATE " . $eloquentModel->getTable() . " SET location = GeomFromText('POINT(" . $point . ")') WHERE id = ". $eloquentModel->id);
        }

    });
}
```

About migrations, like @jhmilan says you can always use the Schema::create and DB::statement methods to customize the migration.

```
Schema::create('locations', function($table){
        $table->engine = "MYISAM";
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('latitude', 10, 8); 
        $table->decimal('longitude', 11, 8);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    /*Espatial Column*/
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE locations ADD location POINT NOT NULL' );
    /*Espatial index (MYISAM only)*/
    DB::statement( 'ALTER TABLE locations ADD SPATIAL INDEX index_point(location)' );
```

Comment: you can now create index on Spatial datatype on Innodb engine. (from Mysql 5.7)

Comment: Where did the `geoToPoint()` came from?

Comment: geoToPoint is only a helper function  to concatenate the latitude and longitude, that returns the following: 
$latitude . " " . $longitude;

Answer (score 6):

It is available to use https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial

you may use:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent\SpatialTrait;

/**
 * @property \Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point $location
 */
class Place extends Model
{
    use SpatialTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    protected $spatialFields = [
        'location',
    ];
}
```

then you are able to run queries on the 'location' field.

to store model you may use:

```
$place1 = new Place();
$place1->name = 'Empire State Building';
$place1->location = new Point(40.7484404, -73.9878441);
$place1->save();
```

to retrieving a model you should use:

```
$place2 = Place::first();
$lat = $place2->location->getLat(); // 40.7484404
$lng = $place2->location->getLng(); // -73.9878441
```